# CSS :not pseudo code not working

Tags: html, css

I want to apply `:not` pseudo code with `li` and with `[aria-hidden=true]` attribute. But it's not working. Please see my below code.
HTML:

```
<li class=" timeframe"><h5 class=" timeframe-title">Jun<span>2015</span></h5>
<ol class=" milestones">
    <li class="milestone-wrapper even"></li>
    <li class="milestone-wrapper even" aria-hidden="true"></li>
    <li class="milestone-wrapper odd" aria-hidden="true"></li>
    <li class="milestone-wrapper even" aria-hidden="true"></li>
</ol>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.milestones .milestone-wrapper:not(li[aria-hidden=true]) {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: From your code above wouldn't it be easier to use `:first-child` instead of a complicated `:not()` selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MDN/CSS/:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not):

> The negation CSS pseudo-class, *:not(X)*, is a functional notation taking a simple selector *X* as an argument.
>
> ...
>
> *Syntax*: *:not(selector) { style properties }*

`[aria-hidden=true]` is a [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) on its own. Remove `li` from `:not(li[aria-hidden=true])`:

```css
.milestones .milestone-wrapper:not([aria-hidden=true]) {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<li class=" timeframe"><h5 class=" timeframe-title">Jun<span>2015</span></h5>
<ol class=" milestones">
    <li class="milestone-wrapper even"></li>
    <li class="milestone-wrapper even" aria-hidden="true"></li>
    <li class="milestone-wrapper odd" aria-hidden="true"></li>
    <li class="milestone-wrapper even" aria-hidden="true"></li>
</ol>
</li>
```